# SQL Procedure - Nothing is printed out

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

When I try to run this code, it doesn't show any output and I don't know why.

This procedure takes in a customer ID and displays all the orders
    made by the specified customer. It uses a cursor to store the details
    of the order and then prints the details.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    create or replace PROCEDURE procedure_CustOrderHistory (cust_id IN number) AS
    CURSOR c_CustOrderHistory  IS

    Select o.order_id, o.order_totalCost, o.order_date, cu.customer_firstName, 
    cu.customer_lastName, s.staff_firstName, s.staff_lastName, os.order_status
    FROM orders o, customer cu, staff s, order_status os
    where o.customer_id=cu.customer_id AND s.staff_id = o.staff_id AND
    os.order_statusID = o.order_statusID and cu.customer_id = cust_id ;

BEGIN
  FOR r_order IN c_CustOrderHistory
  LOOP 
   dbms_output.put_line('Order ID: '||r_order.order_id || ', Order Total Cost: ' || r_order.order_totalCost || 'BHD, Order Date: ' || r_order.order_date || ', Customer Name: ' || r_order.customer_firstName || ' ' || r_order.customer_lastName|| ', Customer Name: ' || r_order.customer_firstName || ' ' || r_order.customer_lastName || ', Order Status: '|| r_order.order_status);              
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This anonymous block tests the previous procedure. It asks the user
    for an ID and then calls the procedure by passing in the customer ID.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  v_custid number := &customerid;
BEGIN
  procedure_CustOrderHistory(v_custid);
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Customer ID not found.');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error! ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]. All we can say about this is: if you have no data that corresponds to the WHERE clause and no error occurs, this query will print nothing.

Comment: Where are you running this? E.g. in SQL*Plus, you'd need a forward slash after both sets of code

Comment: As Tom Kyte says, that's like going to your mechanic and saying "My car won't start, and I don't know why"...

Comment: I am not an Oracle expert. But in SQL Server, if we concatenate NULL values, we won't get result. Here, you are concatenating so many columns. Check whether any of them returns NULL and because of that you are not getting. **It is just my Guess and not result of analysis**

Answer (score 0):

A cursor loop doesn't throw NO_DATA_FOUND. So if your query returns no rows the cursor will loop zero times and exit elegantly.

So most likely what has happened is either there are no `customer` records for the ID you pass at the prompt or there is some other logical problem in the cursor query (say, the customer has no orders).

You can test my theory by adding a counter like this:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE procedure_CustOrderHistory (cust_id IN number) AS
    CURSOR c_CustOrderHistory  IS

    Select o.order_id, o.order_totalCost, o.order_date, cu.customer_firstName, 
    cu.customer_lastName, s.staff_firstName, s.staff_lastName, os.order_status
    FROM orders o, customer cu, staff s, order_status os
    where o.customer_id=cu.customer_id AND s.staff_id = o.staff_id AND
    os.order_statusID = o.order_statusID and cu.customer_id = cust_id ;
    rec_ctr pls_integer := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR r_order IN c_CustOrderHistory
  LOOP 
    rec_ctr := rec_ctr +1;
   dbms_output.put_line('#'|| rec_ctr ||' '|| 
           'Order ID: '||r_order.order_id || ', Order Total Cost: ' || r_order.order_totalCost || 'BHD, Order Date: ' || r_order.order_date || ', Customer Name: ' || r_order.customer_firstName || ' ' || r_order.customer_lastName|| ', Customer Name: ' || r_order.customer_firstName || ' ' || r_order.customer_lastName || ', Order Status: '|| r_order.order_status);              
  END LOOP;
  if rec_ctr = 0 then
     raise no_data_found;
  end if;
END;
```

This explicitly raises an exception if the loop processed no rows.

---

> ".However, even if I enter a valid CustomerID it doesn't display it. Do you have any idea?"

Your query joins four tables. So you need to work through the logic of the query to make sure:

1. the join conditions are specified correctly
2. there is matching data in the tables

For instance, does the customer you enter have any orders? If yes, do their orders have a valid order status. Is the order staff ID a valid one?

Comment: Thankyou! It worked and showed an error as an output.However, even if I enter a valid CustomerID it doesn't display it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: If the this answer helped you should upvote and/or accept it. Accepted answers improve StackOverflow as a resource for future Seekers.